# How to use regx to find the characters in the string

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string which is like
`abc0<system id="101" display-name="abc1">abc1</system>abc1<system id="101" display-name="abc2">abc2</system>abc2`
how can I use regular expression to find any `abc0` and `abc1` and `abc2` which are not inside `<system></system>` tag.
Is is possible to use python re to find them?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why would you use RegExp for this? Use a proper HTML/XML parser instead - there are too many edge cases in this type of markup for RegExp to be helpful.

Comment: See [Don't use regex for everything](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info#:~:text=Don%27t%20use%20regex%20for%20everything!) section in the [tag:regex] tag info.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to first strip off all `<system>` tags.  Then do a regex find all for `abc\d+`:

```py
inp = 'abc0<system id="101" display-name="abc1">abc1</system>abc1<system id="101" display-name="abc2">abc2</system>abc2'
inp = re.sub(r'<system[^>]*>.*?</system>', '', inp)
matches = re.findall(r'abc\d+', inp)
print(matches)  # ['abc0', 'abc1', 'abc2']
```